# What if accessing a non-existing physical address in X86 system?

Tags: memory-management, x86-64, memory-address

I am working on a Linux kernel module, which maps a physical address range to a process virtual address space, by playing with process's page tables.
Then, I have a question in my head, what will happen if a PTE points to a non-existing physical address?
For example, my X86 laptop has 8GB DRAM, and if a PTE has the value of 0x8000000400001227, will the CPU generate some exception for this invalid address accessing?
I did a quick a test with that, but there is NOthing unusual happened, and I got confused totally.

Please help clarifying the reason behind, or let me know if I really need to read some X86 documents.

Comment: Have you considered the swap size (or pagefile in win lingo)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Comment: In fact, before I read your comments, i did NOT consider swap space. With your comments, I checked my Linux system, and the swap size is only 1GB, so RAM + SWAP = 9GB. I set the PTE to point to 16GB, it should be non-existing, right? I have one further question, how does CPU use the PTE? I mean, how does it know to access RAM or SWAP space? I think access swap is done by OS page fault handler. So do you mean the 0x400000000 triggered a #PF? Or the answer to my original question is accessing non-existing physical address can trigger page fault in CPU?

Comment: Swap is handled by software. Hardware paging doesn't have anything to do with it, except that if a page is not present, hardware generates a page fault, so that software can retrieve the page.

Comment: @norok2: This question is about physical address space, not virtual address space.  Handling valid pagefault to implement virtual memory is totally separate.

Answer (score 3):

Typically a memory read to non-existent memory will return all FF's and a memory write will be discarded. (With some platforms and/or some address ranges, reads may return 0. It depends on how the address range is decoded by the chipset.)

Page table entry bits 51:M are reserved (where M is the physical address width supported by the processor), so if you map and try to access an address greater than the physical address width, you will get a page fault due to a reserved bit violation. I think M is typically 39 bits for clients; more for servers. You can find out the value for your system using CPUID with eax=80000008 and examining bits 7:0 of eax.

Comment: In my Linux system the M is 43, so 0x400000000 is a valid address, but it is NOT existing in my 8GB RAM system.   My tests shown your comments/answer is correct. But in KVM guest (Ubuntu Linux), the data read is 0, not 0xFF, I don't know why. I got surprised that I can read data from non-existing address without any error. My assumption is there should be some exception triggered by hardware (chipset as you mentioned) for that access, but it seems not right.