# Why does address range 0xC0000000 ~ 0xFFFFFFFF always give 0x00 or 0xFF after switching to protected mode before enabling paging?

Tags: x86, nasm, memory-address, bootloader, osdev

I'm making a custom boot loader, and currently in the stage of enabling paging after switching to protected mode. I tried to check all memory range is usable from 0x00000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF to make sure my kernel has full control over memories. Checking is done by copying value to the memory address and printing the value through video memory(0xB8000). But the address range from 0xC0000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF always contains 0x00(if executed by QEMU) or 0xFF(if executed in real hardware through legacy booting).

I've been searching for the reason for last 3 weeks but failed to find a clear answer. From searching, I've found some clues like physical-virtual address translation, kernel mode and user mode, MMU, reserved hardware memory range.

- The phenomenon is due to physical-virtual address translation.

  > The boot loader is in protected mode and paging is not enabled. So the address in the code, which is virtual(= linear) address, is translated by 1:1 mapping.

Virtual address : 0x12345678 -> Physical address : 0x12345678

It seems it is unrelated to the phenomenon-particular address range always containing 0x00 or 0xFF.

- The phenomenon is due to kernel mode and user mode.

  > There were numerous articles about kernel mode and user mode especially about linux. But my boot loader hasn't done enabled paging yet.

Therefore, there is no rule defined such as
- user/kernel space range
ex)
User memory space : 0x00000000 to 0xBFFFFFFF
Kernel memory space : 0xC0000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF
- how virtual memory will be mapped
virtual memory 0x00010000 -> 0xC0010000
- pages

- The phenomenon is due to MMU

  > It seems it is related to translation, and nothing to do with particular memory range containing 0x00 or 0xFF.
- The phenomenon is due to reserved memory.

  > I thought this as highly likely the main reason, and executed memory detection by BIOS interrupt 0x15 eax 0xE820. The result 'it was not'.
  >   Also, checked intel datasheet.

Now, I have no idea why is this happening.

Why is memory range from 0xC0000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF always contains 0x00 or 0xFF? (Describing 'always contain 0x00 or 0xFF' because I am unsure about whether
- memory is inaccessible
- memory is not writable
- memory is not readable
- etc
)

The result and codes are posted below.

■ BootLoader.asm

```
%include "MBR.asm"
%include "BootSector2.asm"
```

■ MBR.asm

```
[ORG 0x0000]
[BITS 16]

; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
; EQU
; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

MBRBaseAddress:     equ     0x7C00
ReadSectorCount:    equ     0x0001

; ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
; Code Section
; ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

SECTION .text

MBR:

; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
; Initialize Registers
; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

    jmp     0x0000:(MBRBaseAddress + 0x0005)                                ; Initialize CS (Code Segment) Register / Absolute Far Jump / set cs = 0x0000, jump to 0x07C05 (0x7C00 + 0x0005)

    mov     ax, word 0x0000
    mov     ds, ax                                                          ; Initialize DS (Data Segment) Register
    mov     ss, ax                                                          ; Initialize SS (Stack Segment) Register
    mov     ax, word 0x1000
    mov     es, ax                                                          ; Initialize ES (Extra Segment) Register
    mov     ax, word 0xB800
    mov     fs, ax                                                          ; Initialize FS Register

    mov     ax, word 0x0000                                                 ; Initialize AX (Accumulator) Register
    mov     bx, word 0x0000                                                 ; Initialize BX (Base) Register
    mov     cx, word 0x0000                                                 ; Initialize CX (Count) Register
    mov     dx, word 0x0000                                                 ; Initialize DX (Data) Register
    mov     si, word 0x0000                                                 ; Initialize SI (Source Index) Register
    mov     di, word 0x0000                                                 ; Initialize DI (Destination Index) Register
    mov     sp, word 0xFFFE                                                 ; Initialize SP (Stack Pointer) Register
    mov     bp, word 0xFFFE                                                 ; Initialize BP (Base Pointer) Register

; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
; Clear Screen
; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

.Clear1Digit:

    mov     [fs:di], word 0x0A00                                            ; [0xB800:di] 0x00 / [0xB800:di + 1] 0x0A / 0 -> 0000 (Background Attribute) / A -> 1010 (Text Attribute)
    add     di, 2
    cmp     di, 2 * 80 * 25                                                 ; Compare di to 2 * 80 * 25 (= 4000 = 0x0FA0)
    jl      .Clear1Digit

    mov     di, word 0x0000                                                 ; Clear di

; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
; Print String : Real Mode String
; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

    push    RealModeString
    push    0
    call    .PrintString
    mov     sp, bp

; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
; Print String : Start Reading Sectors String
; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

    push    StartReadingSectorsString
    push    1 * 2 * 80
    call    .PrintString
    mov     sp, bp

; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
; Read Sectors (via BIOS interrupt)
; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

.ReadSectors:

    mov     si, word 0x0000                                                 ; Initialize si (Read sector count)

    mov     al, 1                                                           ; Initialize read sector count (1)
    mov     dl, byte 0x80                                                   ; Initialize drive to read from (Hard Disk C:)
    mov     bx, word 0x0000                                                 ; Offset to read to
    mov     ah, byte 0x02                                                   ; BIOS interrupt : Read sector

.Read1Sector:

    mov     ch, byte [MBRBaseAddress + CylinderIndex]                       ; Set cylinder value to read from
    mov     dh, byte [MBRBaseAddress + HeadIndex]                           ; Set head value to read from
    mov     cl, byte [MBRBaseAddress + SectorIndex]                         ; Set sector value to read from

    cmp     si, ReadSectorCount                                             ; Compare si to ReadSectorCount
    jge     .ReadSectorsEnd                                                 ; Jump to .ReadSectorsEnd if

    int     0x13                                                            ; Call BIOS interrupt

    add     si, 1
    add     cl, 1
    mov     [MBRBaseAddress + SectorIndex], cl
    add     bx, 512
    jmp     .Read1Sector

.ReadSectorsEnd:

; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
; Print Value : Sectors Read Count
; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

    push    si
    push    2 * 2 * 80
    call    .PrintValue
    mov     sp, bp

; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
; Print String : Sectors Read String
; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

    push    SectorsReadString
    push    (2 * 2 * 80) + (2 * 5)
    call    .PrintString
    mov     sp, bp

; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
; Switch to Protected Mode
; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

    cli
    lgdt    [MBRBaseAddress + GDT]
    ;mov        eax, dword 0x4000003B
    mov     eax, cr0
    or      al, 1
    mov     cr0, eax

    jmp     dword 0x0008:0x00010000

; ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
; Functions
; ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
; Print Value
; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

.PrintValue:

    push    bp                                                              ; Copy current bp to memory whose address is current sp
    mov     bp, sp                                                          ; Set new bp by current sp

    mov     cl, byte 12                                                     ; Initialize cl (Shift right count)
    mov     di, [bp + 4]                                                    ; Initialize di (2nd argument / Video memory offset where to print)

.PrintValueLoop:

    mov     si, [bp + 6]                                                    ; Copy 1st argument (Value to print) to si
    shr     si, cl                                                          ; Shift right si cl times
    and     si, word 0x000F                                                 ; Keep last 4 bits and discard (fill) other bytes to 0
    mov     bl, byte [MBRBaseAddress + ASCIIString + si]                    ; Copy ASCII value, corresponding to si, to bl
    mov     [fs:di], bl                                                     ; [0xB800:di] bl / Copy 1 character to video memory

    sub     cl, 4
    add     di, 2
    cmp     cl, 0
    jg      .PrintValueLoop

    mov     si, [bp + 6]                                                    ; Copy 1st argument (Value to print) to si
    and     si, word 0x000F                                                 ; Keep last 4 bits and discard (fill) other bytes to 0
    mov     bl, byte [MBRBaseAddress + ASCIIString + si]                    ; Copy ASCII value, corresponding to si, to bl
    mov     [fs:di], bl                                                     ; [0xB800:di] bl / Copy 1 character to video memory

.PrintValueEnd:

    pop     bp                                                              ; Copy memory whose address is current sp to bp
    ret

; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
; Print String
; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

.PrintString:

    push    bp                                                              ; Copy current bp to memory whose address is current sp
    mov     bp, sp                                                          ; Set new bp by current sp

    mov     bx, word [bp + 6]                                               ; Initialize bx (1st argument / String offset)
    mov     si, 0                                                           ; Initialize si (String index)
    mov     di, word [bp + 4]                                               ; Initialize di (2nd argument / Video memory offset where to print)

.PrintStringLoop:

    mov     cl, byte [MBRBaseAddress + bx + si]                             ; Copy 1 character from memory (MBRBaseAddress + String offset + String index) to cl
    cmp     cl, 0                                                           ; Compare cl to 0
    je      .PrintStringEnd
    mov     [fs:di], cl                                                     ; [0xB800:di] cl / Copy 1 character to video memory

    add     si, 1
    add     di, 2
    jmp     .PrintStringLoop

.PrintStringEnd:

    pop     bp                                                              ; Copy memory whose address is current sp to bp
    ret

; ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
; Data (Read Only)
; ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
; ASCII String
; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

ASCIIString:

    db      '0123456789ABCDEF', 0

; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
; Strings
; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

RealModeString:

    db      '[Current Mode : Real Mode]', 0

StartReadingSectorsString:

    db      'Start Reading Sectors', 0

SectorsReadString:

    db      'Sectors Read', 0

; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
; Cylinder, Head, Sector Index
; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

CylinderIndex:

    db      0x00

HeadIndex:

    db      0x00

SectorIndex:

    db      0x02

; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
; GDT (Global Descriptor Table)
; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

GDTStart:
GDTNullDescriptor:

    dq      0x0000000000000000

GDTCodeDescriptor:

    dw      0xFFFF
    dw      0x0000
    db      0x00
    db      0x9A
    db      0xCF
    db      0x00

GDTDataDescriptor:

    dw      0xFFFF
    dw      0x0000
    db      0x00
    db      0x92
    db      0xCF
    db      0x00

GDTEnd:
GDT:

    dw      GDTEnd - GDTStart
    dd      MBRBaseAddress + GDTStart

; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
; Declare Zeros
; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

    times   510 - ($ - $$)  db  0x00

; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
; Boot Signature
; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

    dw      0xAA55
```

■ BootSector2.asm

```
[BITS 32]

; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
; EQU
; ──────────────────────────────────────────────────

BootSector2BaseOffset:      equ     0x0000FE00                              ; ※ 0x00010000 (Read sector address) - 0x00000200 (Initial label offset) = 0x0000FE00 in order to use label as if it begins from 0x00000000 [ex) BootSector2Offset (0x0000FE00) + LABEL (0x000002XX) = 0x000100XX]
VideoMemory:                equ     0x000B8000

BootSector2:

    mov     ax, word 0x0010
    mov     ds, ax
    mov     es, ax
    mov     fs, ax
    mov     gs, ax
    mov     ss, ax

    mov     eax, dword 0x000B8000
    mov     ebx, dword 0x00000000
    mov     cl, 28
    mov     esi, dword 0x00000000
    mov     edi, dword VideoMemory + (3 * 2 * 80)
    mov     esp, dword 0xFFFC0004;0xBFFFFFFC;0xC0000000 + 0x00010000 + 0x000000E4
    mov     ebp, dword 0xFFFC0004;0xBFFFFFFC;0xC0000000 + 0x00010000 + 0x000000E4

.Loop1:

    mov     esi, esp
    shr     esi, cl
    and     esi, dword 0x0000000F

    mov     bl, byte [MBRBaseAddress + ASCIIString + esi]
    mov     [edi], bl

    sub     cl, 4
    add     edi, 2
    cmp     cl, 0
    jg      .Loop1

    mov     esi, esp
    and     esi, dword 0x0000000F

    mov     bl, byte [MBRBaseAddress + ASCIIString + esi]
    mov     [edi], bl


    mov     edi, dword VideoMemory + (4 * 2 * 80)
    push    dword 0xABCD1234
    mov     cl, 28


.Loop2:

    mov     esi, esp
    shr     esi, cl
    and     esi, dword 0x0000000F

    mov     bl, byte [MBRBaseAddress + ASCIIString + esi]
    mov     [edi], bl

    sub     cl, 4
    add     edi, 2
    cmp     cl, 0
    jg      .Loop2

    mov     esi, esp
    and     esi, dword 0x0000000F

    mov     bl, byte [MBRBaseAddress + ASCIIString + esi]
    mov     [edi], bl


    mov     edi, dword VideoMemory + (5 * 2 * 80)
    mov     cl, 28

.Loop3:

    mov     esi, dword [0xFFFC0000]
    shr     esi, cl
    and     esi, dword 0x0000000F

    mov     bl, byte [MBRBaseAddress + ASCIIString + esi]
    mov     [edi], bl

    sub     cl, 4
    add     edi, 2
    cmp     cl, 0
    jg      .Loop3

    mov     esi, dword [0xFFFC0000]
    and     esi, dword 0x0000000F

    mov     bl, byte [MBRBaseAddress + ASCIIString + esi]
    mov     [edi], bl

    jmp     $

; ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
; Data (Read Only)
; ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

ProtectedModeString:

    db      '[Current Mode : Protected Mode]', 0

SampleValue:

    dd      0x12345678

    times   1024 - ($ - $$) db 0x00
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hha2e.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xj2q.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVjYu.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHxGm.png)

Comment: A question can't be that long. IMHO, you should make it shorter in order to receive an answer.

Comment: Thank you ceremcem. I will reorganize and trim the content shorter.

Comment: I haven't looked at all the code but you should really be enabling the A20 line especially if on real hardware. Although it may be enabled, it is possible it isn't. https://wiki.osdev.org/A20_Line

Comment: Thank you Sir Michael Petch. The next thing I was going to do before paging was A20 line check and enabling. I will enable A20 and check whether the phenomenon disappears.

Comment: As well video card memory often start at physcal address 0xc0000000

Comment: Not sure it will be your issue or not (or a contributing factor). Was just an observation. Are you sure the memory at 0xc0000000 is usable memory? Does the memory map say that it is available? If a memory range isn't identified by E820 memory map then the range should be considered as not present

Comment: According to int 0x15 eax 0xE820, 0xBFFE0000 ~ 0xC0000000 is reserved. 0xC0000001 ~ 0xFFFBFFFF is not shown (descriptor jumps from 0xBFFE0000 ~ 0xC0000000 to 0xFFFC0000 ~ 0xFFFFFFFF). So, the unshown memory address 0xC0000001 ~ 0xFFFBFFFF should be considered as not present.

Comment: Coincidentally there is a very recent question (and a good answer) about the phenomenon of reading/writing data to memory regions that aren't present: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56763862/what-if-accessing-a-non-existing-physical-address-in-x86-system

Comment: If a range isn't shown it should be considered not present and you shouldn't be testing it or using it. It is unclear why you are testing memory though. The E820 map should be all that you need in most circumstances.

Comment: Basically between 0xc0000000 and the end of memory (the last 1 gigabyte) much of the area may be associated with Memory mapped PCI devices, Video Ram, PnP NVRAM, IO APICs, local APICs, the BIOS etc. How much of it and where is dependent on the hardware and will vary from BIOS to BIOS and motherboard type to motherboard type.

Comment: OH! The link you've given answers "Typically a memory read to non-existent memory will return all FF's and a memory write will be discarded." Thank you! The reason why I tried to copy to memory addresses was to check 'what I have understood is correct'. The article or lectures or books I've seen said 'after switching to protected mode, memory address from 0x00000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF is all accessible', I wanted to make sure which addresses accessible or usable and what happens if I access or copy to inaccessible or unusable memory addresses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What if accessing a non-existing physical address in X86 system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56763862/what-if-accessing-a-non-existing-physical-address-in-x86-system) . I'm marking this as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: The memory range for PCIe config space is in that area (on real hardware; perhaps not in qemu). It definitely won’t be all 0 or all 1. You can find the exact address range for it in the ACPI MCFG table.

Comment: Also, so many articles were explaining about virtual memory in linux that 0x00000000 ~ 0xBFFFFFFF is user memory 0xC0000000 is kernel memory and these ranges were os designer's decision. My boot loader is in kernel mode and I haven't set or instructed anything related to memory address 0xC0000000, so I got doubtful why copying value in it was showing 0x00 or 0xFF.

Comment: That is talking about virtual address ranges, not physical.

Comment: Sorry about my relies seem awkward, my responds are pre-previous comment of yours..

Comment: Thank you prl. I will look for 'ACPI MCFG table' as keyword.

Comment: prl. I think I don't understand what 'that' mean from "That is talking about virtual address ranges, not physical". Would it be bothering if I ask for detail?

Comment: You **must** use the E820 map for detecting memory. While it's possible to get the memory map from the hardware configuration, the problem is that *some usable memory* is used by the firmware for storing the ACPI tables and similar.

Comment: The articles that say that the upper one-fourth of the address space is kernel memory are talking about virtual address space. But your question is about physical address space (since you haven’t enabled paging). So they are completely unrelated.